# Hive External Table vs Internal table commands

Tags: hadoop, hive

Assuming I have these two tables:

**External**:

```
create external table emp_feedback (
  emp_id int,
  emp_name string
)
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/contacts';
```

**Internal**:

```
create table emp_feedback (
  emp_id int,
  emp_name string
)
LOAD DATA INPATH 'file_location_of_csv' INTO TABLE emp_feedback;
```

1. When I say: `LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/contacts';` for the external table does that mean that the data for that table is found in the directory `'/user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/contacts';`? So that directory has to exist in HDFS before hand?
2. Can I use `LOAD DATA INPATH...` for an `external` table or is that only used for `internal` tables. And vice versa can I use `Location...` for an internal table?

Comment: Yes, you can use location for internal tables and load data inpath for both type of tables. You can also create External table without providing location, it will take default location of your schema/warehouse directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (a) Yes. You are right, it means that the data is found in that location/directory
2. (b) No. The directory doesn't have to exist to create a Schema, Hive will create the directory if it doesn't exist. But there is no point in doing as your table will be empty therefore your query will be empty. But in the future, you can move data to that location and use that table.
3. (a) `LOAD DATA INPATH` can be used for both external and internal tables. When you do, it moves the data, to the location specified by the schema (for external tables) or to `/.../warehouse/...` (for internal tables)
4. (b) `location` can be specified for both internal and external tables. But when you drop the internal table, it will also remove the data from that location, whereas only meta data information is removed for external tables.

Comment: Assuming you created an external table and specified some `LOCATION` let's say `/user/temp/employee`. Now if you use `LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/files/employee.csv INTO employee` it will actually move the data from employee.csv into the `/user/temp/employee`. But when you drop the employee table the data at `/user/temp/employee` will still stay?

Answer (score 0):

**load data inpath** command is use to load data into hive table. 'LOCAL' signifies that the input file is on the local file system. If 'LOCAL' is omitted then it looks for the file in HDFS.

```
load data inpath '/path/file.csv' into mytable; 
load data local inpath '/Local path/file.csv' into mytable;
```

This command will remove content at source directory and create a internal table

**LOCATION** keyword allow to points to any HDFS location for its storage, rather than being stored in a folder specified by the configuration property hive.metastore.warehouse.dir.

In other words, with specified LOCATION '/your path/', Hive does not use a default location for this table. This comes in handy if you already have data generated.

Remember, LOCATION can be specify on EXTERNAL tables only. For regular tables, default location will be used.
Create external table and copy the data into table. Now data won't be moved from source. You can drop external table but still source data is available.

When you drop an external table, it only drops the meta data of HIVE table. Data still exists at HDFS file location.

To summarize, load data inpath tell hive where to look for input files and LOCATION keyword tells hive where to save output files on HDFS.